# Rename a particular instance in multiple files with the file name?

Tags: python, bash, perl

I had to create about 500 copies of a xml file in the directory, which I managed to get done. As a part of the next problem is that I want to rename particular text in the file. How can I go about doing it?

This is what I have:
1000.xml, 1001.xml, 1002.xml...

1000.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
<address>
    <name>Joe Tester</name>
    <street>Baker street 5</street>
    <id>1000</id>
</address>
<count>1000</count>
```

Essentially, this is copied to all the other files, but with a numerical and chronological name. How do I replace this "1000" with the "file name"? So, the new file should be -
1001.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='test.xsd'>
    <address>
        <name>Joe Tester</name>
        <street>Baker street 5</street>
        <id>1001</id>
    </address>
    <count>1001</count>
</addresses>
```

I could do only this - `sed -i '' -e 's/1000/1001/g' $(find . -type f)` which will replace all the 1000 with 1001, but not the file name.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  This seems like a pretty simple shell scripting task.  Maybe a `for` loop?

Comment: I posted the sed command I could think of. But it renames all the 1000 to 1001. However, it should be 1002 in file 1002.xml, 1003 in 1003.xml and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged it `perl` so here's how I'd do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
#iterate the files. 
foreach my $xml_file ( glob "*.xml" ) { 
    #regex match the number for the XML. 
    my ( $file_num ) = $xml_file =~ m/(\d+).xml/; 
    #create an XML::Twig, and set it to 'indented' output. 
    XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented',
          #matches elements and runs the subroutine on 'it'. ($_) is the 
          #current element in this context. 
                       twig_handlers => { 'address/id' => sub { $_ -> set_text($file_num) }, 
                                          'count'      => sub { $_ -> set_text($file_num) },  
           #parsefile_inplace reads and writes back any changes to the file
           #as it goes. 
                                        } ) -> parsefile_inplace($xml_file); 


}
```

This uses `XML::Twig`, which allows you do an in place edit. It does this via the element handlers, which upon hitting a suitable match, replaces the content with the right numeric value for the file.

I've opted to replace the defined content for `address/id` and `count`, rather than just doing straight search and replace, because then ... you don't have to worry about `1000` showing up anywhere else in the content. (Like the address).

Answer (score 2):

After deciphering your question I see you want to change actual content in the xml file i.e the id or some other node's text to the name of the file so use an xml parser like [*lxml*](http://lxml.de/)

```
from  glob import iglob
import lxml.etree as et

for fle in iglob("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml"):
    tree = et.parse(fle)
    id_ = tree.find(".//id").text = fle
    tree.write(fle, encoding="utf-8")
```

If you want to change the count also use:

```
 for fle in iglob("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml"):
        tree = et.parse(fle)
        id_, count = tree.find(".//id"), tree.find(".//count")
        id_.text = count.text = fle
        tree.write(fle, encoding="utf-8")
```

Whatever text you want to set to the file name just look for the node with find and set the text use the *node.text = ...* logic. If you want to use the name ignoring the extension just split:

```
for fle in iglob("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml"):
        tree = et.parse(fle)
        id_, count = tree.find(".//id"), tree.find(".//count")
        id_.text = count.text = fle.split(".")[0]
        tree.write(fle, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic. How do I edit the file content in id, count to the file name?

Comment: @Metahuman,that is what the second snippet does, follow it with `tree.write(fle, encoding="utf-8")` and it will write the new data, I edited the answer.

Comment: Are you just wanting to replace to replace the 1000 with 1001  etc... or use the full filename?

Comment: Just the number. I found out how to get it done with your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, it is just a matter of removing the extension

Answer (score 1):

Try your sed command in a loop-

```
for i in {1000..1500} #or whatever your maximum number is
do
sed -i "s/1000/"$i"/g" "$i".xml
done
```

Comment: I'm really not sure this is a good solution. It works, but.... handling XML without parsing it is pretty much always hacky at best.

Comment: If you know the context will always include the brokets, maybe do `"s/>1000</>$i</g"`